# How to make a table in mysql for this xml and after table creation how to import?

Tags: mysql, xml

This is my XML code I want to import it to MySql database but I don't know how to create a  table for this XML so please guide me that i can import the XML code to the database. The code is given below.

```
 <states>
     <state name ="city1" colour="#009900">
      <point lat="475331583" lng="67.08251953125"/>
      <point lat="137335685307" lng="36328125"/>
      <point lat="044673317843" lng="67.1484375"/>
      <point lat="210237943" lng="6625"/>
    </state>

    <state name ="city2" color="#009900">
     <point lat="344.44" lng="64444"/>
     <point lat="256557" lng="4444"/>
     <point lat="25.955544" lng="67.1484375"/>
     <point lat="243" lng="665625"/>
   </state>

   <state name ="city3" color="#009900">
    <point lat="344.44" lng="64444"/>
    <point lat="256557" lng="4444"/>
    <point lat="25.955544" lng="65"/>
    <point lat="243" lng="665625"/>
  </state>
 </states>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the table, see [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE states (
    name  VARCHAR(255),
    color CHAR(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE statePoints (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    lat  DECIMAL(50,25),
    lng  DECIMAL(50,25),
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES states (name)
);
```

To import the data, see [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html):

```sql
LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/file.xml'
    INTO TABLE states
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<state>';

LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/file.xml'
    INTO TABLE statePoints
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<point>';
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML INFILE 'states.xml'
    INTO TABLE states
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<state>'' at line 1  SIR whwn i try i received this error.what i do sir?

Comment: @user2826778: `LOAD XML INFILE` was added in MySQL v5.5.  What version are you using?

Comment: i am using MySQL version :5.0.45

Comment: @user2826778: Then you will have to either upgrade MySQL, install suitable a UDF, or parse/transform the XML externally.

Comment: Sir thank you for your help. i have created the tables and loaded the data into  both tables.now i want to extract the stored data in xml form  in the same format as i have given above please sir guide me.i will be highly than ful to you please sir guide me.

Comment: @user2826778: MySQL isn't the best tool for that job (although, again, there may be a suitable UDF which could help).  Either do it within the presentation layer of your application, or else choose another database management system - perhaps a native XML one?

Comment: i want to  export the data which is loaded into database in the same format as above what i do for that.

Comment: @user2826778: MySQL isn't the best tool for that job (although, again, there may be a suitable UDF which could help). Either do it within the presentation layer of your application, or else choose another database management system - perhaps a native XML one?

Comment: sir would you like to guide me "making polygons on google map from latitude and longitude which are stored in database"

Comment: @user2826778: Please ask that as a new question.